# How to avoid Custom EL Function workaround?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, el

I am trying to understand the failure of my custom EL function compared to a  standard EL function.  I defined custom EL functions, funcForJS and funcForHTML to be used within embedded javascript and within the normal HTML markup in my JSP file.   I discovered that while the funcForHTML referenced within the normal HTML markup block was resolved successfully, the funcForJS used within my embedded javascript was "not found".  Is it bad practice to leverage EL functions in embedded JavaScript?  Regardless - is it supposed to work like I'm trying it?  The error reported to the browser was:

**Error 500: javax.el.ELException: Function 'myel:funcForJS' not found**

The custom function java file is:

```
package my.test;
public class MyELFuncs {
  public static java.lang.String funcForJS(java.lang.String str) {
    return str+" JS";
  }
  public static java.lang.String funcForHTML(java.lang.String str) {
    return str+" HTML";
  }
}
```

and the custom tld file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<short-name>MyTagLibrary</short-name>
<uri>/MyTagLibrary</uri>

<function>
    <description>Returns the same string with JS on end</description>
        <name>funcForJS</name>
        <function-class>my.test.MyELFuncs</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String funcForJS( java.lang.String )</function-signature>
</function>

<function>
    <description>Returns the same string with HTML on end</description>
        <name>funcForHTML</name>
        <function-class>my.test.MyELFuncs</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String funcForHTML( java.lang.String )</function-signature>
</function>
</taglib>
```

and within the JSP I have this:

```
<%@page session="true" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/MyTagLibrary" prefix="myel" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<html>
 <head>
 <title>Process CAP Receive</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // the standard function fn:trim works fine here
    var standardFnTrimStr = "${fn:trim('  this test str  ')}";

    // my custom function throws error
    var myCustFuncStr = "${myel:funcForJS('some test text')}";
    console.log("standardFnTrimStr="+standardFnTrimStr+", myCustFuncStr="+myCustFuncStr);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>${myel:funcForHTML("this is in HTML block")}</label>
  </body>
</html>
```

and within the web.xml I have this:

```
<taglib>
  <taglib-uri>/MyTagLibrary</taglib-uri>
  <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/config/myCustomTags.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

NOTE: I have discovered a work-around which appears necessary for my custom myel:funcForJS but not for the standard fn:trim.  The work-around is that when I place a dummy reference to the myel:funcForJS anywhere in the html body that is OUTSIDE of the script block, then the myel:funcForJS within the script block successfully resolves.  I didn't have to do that for the fn:trim function, so what could be different about my custom funcForJS?  What am I missing?

Comment: any reason you have myel.funcForJS and not myel:funcForJS?

Comment: Typo for this example.  In my code I used the correct colon ":".  Will try to correct the example above.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use full URI as uri? I have never seen it used with relative i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/okorng

Comment: I forget the different URI syntax that I did already try that also failed.  I'll try a full URI now.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay - I replaced /MyTagLibrary URI, as defined in the tld file, the jsp file, and the web.xml file to be `http://my.host.here/MyTagLibrary`  and saw the same failure.  No improvement with the URI change.  All three URI values in those locations need to be identical - correct?

Comment: I get that the normal parsing order of a browser page is to load javascript and execute before parsing and executing the normal HTML, so in that sense I'm wondering if the timing of the parsing is preventing the custom EL function to resolve.  But - if placing a reference to the same custom EL function anywhere in the normal HMTL is a work-around, then does that imply that the HTML is somehow parsed before the javascript block(s)?  There's a timing issue that appears to be affecting the behavior in an unexpected way.

Comment: EL function are resolved on server side, before any HTML/JS processing is done

Comment: That makes me think that they EL function should be resolved regardless of where in the JSP page it's found.  Right?  Shouldn't matter if it's in the `<script>` block or not?

Comment: yes placement is irrelevan, JSP doesnt care it produces HTML or any other format. It could even generate PNG